# Scrollable div print issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

Why is firefox printing only first page instead of all pages where as chrome prints all pages?

When I am using scrollable div to print, it is taking only first page to print. But even after removing overflow and height from div, it is printing only first page.

CSS :

```
element.style {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: left;
    height: 434px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.grdControll {
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div style="float:left;overflow:scroll;overflow-x: hidden;background:#fff;height:434px;" class="grdControll scroll-pane-grid boxflex" id="grid"></div>
```